# Ingress is creating two ALB instead of one

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using EKS on AWS (EKS version: 1.21), And I  deployed two different applications on two different name spaces.
when I deploy the ingress its creating for me two Application loadbalancers instead of one ALB,
I want to have one ALB with several ingress pointing to two different namespaces

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: tenant1
  name: ingress-apps
  labels:
    app: ingress-app
  annotations:
    # Ingress Core Settings
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    # Health Check Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '15'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-group 
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /app1/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: user-service-app-nodeport-service
                port:
                  number: 80
  ---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: tenant2
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
  annotations:
    # Ingress Core Settings
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    # Health Check Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '15'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-group 
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /app2/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx-app-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: You're using kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nlb" and "alb" at the same time. Is this by mistake? Also you should specify different hostnames for different apps if you want your ABL to work properly. Otherwise how will it know where to route traffic to?

Comment: I corrected the nlb to alb , and added hosts section. But still its creating two ALB's instead of 1

Comment: Can you double check that both ingresses have the same "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name" annotation? Also can you try recreating ingresses from scratch?

Comment: I checked its , its added in both. Should I add it some where else ?? 
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: my-group

Comment: also I am using this ingress controller 
/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.1.9

Comment: try upgrading aws-alb-ingress-controller to latest, which is v2.4

Comment: same issue no changes

Answer (score 0):

Recreating both ingresses solved in my case the issue. Do not attempt to modify an existing ingress which is not part, explicitly via annotations, of a group.
Tested on EKS 1.25 and aws-alb-ingress-controller v2.5.3 .